# Why isn't Anthony "Tony" Janekowski able to close the eyes of the dead body?

Tags: plot-explanation, devil

In *[Devil (2010)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_(2010_film))*, Why can't Anthony "Tony" Janekowski close the eyes of the dead body?

[image]

Every time he tries to close them they're opening back on their own.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but closing a corpse's eyes is generally symbolic of laying their soul to rest.  I'm guessing the fact that the eyes keep opening is meant to suggest that the soul cannot rest peacefully.

Comment: I had my cat put down (she had cancer and was very sick).  The vet injected her and she passed with her eyes open.  I tried to close them and they would not close.  Same as here.  My guess is something in the lid muscles not relaxing immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that her eyes wouldn't close because

> at the end it is revealed that she is the devil, and the one murdering everyone.

Plus it just looks creepy.